# Mingw Shell Console Issue

Tags: c++, c

I recently installed MingW/Msys on my XP Pro box (SP 3).  When I attempt to open a Mingw shell as a console it behaves incorrectly.  The shell window opens for perhaps 5 seconds and then the window closes and the full screen opens up without scroll bars, etc.  I can use this shell display, but it is clumsy and wierd.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?

The same download works fine on a different XP box I have and also on a Win7 box.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you're running the shortcut that points to mysys.bat, not invoking it in some weird way?

Perhaps it's something as silly as Windows having remembered some strange property settings for the window.

Have you tried getting out of full-screen (alt-enter), then checking properties for the window (right click -> properties?)

Things like Window vs. full screen, and screen size versus buffer would come into play here.

When you change the, make sure to select the "to all future windows" option.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and hit alt->enter. Very interesting. The full screen view closed and up popped the MinGW console shell. I checked the buffer on this window, and the screen buffer looks just (50X4) looks just like the screen buffer that goes with the console for cmd.exe--also 50X4. I still don't understand what is going on, but at least I know how to get to a MinGW console that doesn't shut down. Any other ideas would be happily tried.

Comment: I forgot to answer your first question. The answer is that I click on the MSYS icon on the desktop. Nothing wierd. MA

Comment: Perhaps you're running something in your startup scripts (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`) that chokes when it's run in full-screen mode?